# Azure log alert ARM Template deployment fails because of comma in a string parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-monitoring

I want to create an ARM template for Azure Monitor alert which I will deploy via Azure DevOps pipeline. What I want is to pass a string parameter "dl1container,dl1private" into the query, but when I do that the deployment fails with error "message": "Query could not be parsed at ',' on line [3,43]". The noted location in the error message is exactly the point where the comma is in the string parameter.

In the ARM template I am using this code to generate the query:

```
  "DataLakeContainers": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": ""
  }
  },
  "functions": [],
  "variables": {
    "datalakesplit": "[split(parameters('DataLakeContainers'),',')]",
    "datalakesplitformat": "[replace(replace(string(variables('datalakesplit')), '[', ''), ']', '')]",
    "datalakequery": "[format('StorageBlobLogs\n| where TimeGenerated > ago(10m)\n| where ObjectKey has_any ({0})\n| where StatusText !contains \"Success\"\n| summarize count() by StatusText, ObjectKey\n| top 10 by count_ desc', variables('datalakesplitformat'))]"
```

The value to the *DataLakeContainers* is passed from a separate .yml file. I would like to note that the given example works perfectly if I have only one value in the parameter (for example, "dl1container" only) but always fails when I add additional values separated by comma.

Is there any way to use other delimiter in a query which I can pass through the string parameter, or some escape sign which .yml/ Azure DevOps pipeline will accept?

UPDATE:
I have also tried with concut function, but I get the same error as before.

```
"datalakequery": "[concat('StorageBlobLogs\n| where TimeGenerated > ago(10m)\n| where ObjectKey has_any (',variables('datalakesplitformat'),')\n| where StatusText !contains \"Success\"\n| summarize count() by StatusText, ObjectKey\n| top 10 by count_ desc')]",
```